# What do I need to know when creating a non-shell command for a user's login?

Tags: linux, shell, login

I am working on software and configuration for a device that uses Linux.

I have been asked to provide an administrative interface that requires no knowledge of Linux to use and that has restricted capabilities.

I believe that the best way to handle this will be to use a console login (either through ssh or with a serial port) to present a menu of options.  Let's say I have a program called `admin_menu` that handles all my desired tasks.

So, I should be able to create a line in /etc/password like so:

```
admin:x:230:235:Administrative Interface:/home/admin:/local/sbin/admin_menu
```

Are there any special considerations I need to be aware of when I create my `admin_menu` program?  Direct answers are good, but pointers to good docs are even better.

General areas that I want more information on are:

- What environment variables can I expect to be set?  Which ones will I need to set myself?
- Are there any special considerations when spawning child processes?
- What happens upon termination of my menu process?
- Do I use STDIO for interaction with the console or some other interface?

Comment: Good questions. I hoping for those answers, too. I've built a terminal server using minicom-wrappers as login shell. just works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A script can function as a login shell. You will need to add /local/sbin/admin_menu to `/etc/shells`. Otherwise, ssh logins(and possibly others) won't work with no explanation of why(if I remember correctly).

There are some environment variables that will be transferred from the client, such as window size. Some will be set on logging into the system. [PAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_Authentication_Modules) can set some of these, but I don't have an example.

Upon termination of the menu process, the client is logged out, I believe. I base this off of observing what happens when `/bin/bash` terminates.

If I were you, I'd use stdin/stdout for your input and output source.

Answer (score 3):

You can put any program in place of /bin/sh in a /etc/profile entry, whether shell script or executable binary.  The thing you want to watch for is escapes to a shell - if you've tried to capture them in a program, you probably don't want them to get access to a command line.

For example, if the program happened to be something like vi, the user could use ":!/bin/sh" and get to a command line.  Similarly, when using a script, often times user input is used as data in a command line - this can be abused to get a command line as well.  If the menu interface were to prompt you for a file to print which might get used in a command "lpr $input", what happens if the filename typed in is "myfile.txt; /bin/sh"?

There are several other ways of breaking out to a command line, you need to be very careful when setting up a captured account that takes user input.